# Selenium WebDriver keyDown

Tags: java, selenium, keydown

I'm using Selenium in Java and keyDown(Keys.CONTROL) doesn't seem to do anything.
What I want to do is:

- open
  https://demos.devexpress.com/aspxeditorsdemos/ListEditors/MultiSelect.aspx
- click on "Selection mode: Multiple"
- Choose a few different rows at once using keyDown function in
  Selenium

Here is the code:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Selenium\\geckodriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.navigate().to("https://demos.devexpress.com/aspxeditorsdemos/ListEditors/MultiSelect.aspx");

    driver.findElement(By.id("ContentHolder_lbSelectionMode_I")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("ContentHolder_lbSelectionMode_DDD_L_LBI1T0")).click();


    WebElement OneElement = driver.findElement(By.id("ContentHolder_lbFeatures_LBT"));
    List<WebElement> options = OneElement.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
```

//everything is OK until this, I click on "Multiple" and now I try to select a few rows using keyDown:

```
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

    Action multipleSelect = builder.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).click(options.get(2)).click(options.get(4)).click(options.get(6)).build();

    multipleSelect.perform();

    Thread.sleep(5000);

    driver.close();
```

I expect to select a few rows at once but since keyDown is not pressed I get only one selected line in the end.

Comment: You may have to either repeat the keydown for each click inside the build, or do each seperately.  By the way, you're sending a shift, but I'm fairly sure shift-click selects all the items in a list between the first selected item and the currently selected (with shift-click).  What you seem to be wanting to do is control-shift, which allows you to pick multiple items but not necessarily consecutively.  Either way, you'll likely need to do the keydown procedure for each click.

Comment: I tried the following:
Action multipleSelect = builder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(options.get(2)).keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(options.get(4)).keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(options.get(6)).build();

Still doesn't seem to be working... Thank you.

Comment: I tried using those Select differently:
Action multipleSelect = builder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(options.get(2)).build();
multipleSelect.perform();
  
Action multipleSelectTwo1 = builder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(options.get(4)).build();
  
multipleSelectTwo1.perform();

Still doesn't seem to be working. The problem seems to be is that keyDown doesn't work at all...

Comment: That was my best guess, sorry it didn't work.

Comment: Tried to do the same in Google Chrome: works perfectly with a few smalls fixes (like Google Chrome doesn't wait for page to be fully loaded but there are easy workarounds).

Wasted 4 hours looking for such a simple answer. If anyone has an answer why keyDown fails to function in Firefox feel to write it.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple section you can do:

```
Select select = new Select(element);
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
.click(select.getOptions().get(2))
.click(select.getOptions().get(3))
.click(select.getOptions().get(4))
.keyUp(Keys.CONTROL);

builder.build().perform();
```